# IndexedDB errors in Firefox and Chrome: Unknown error and DOMException

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, indexeddb

I am trying to open an IndexedDB in Chrome and firefox. My code:

```
var v = 2;
                    var request = indexedDB.open("orders", v);


                  //Firefox code for db init
                  request.onupgradeneeded = function (e) {

                  console.log("onupgradeneeded");
                    var db = e.target.result;
                    // We can only create Object stores in a setVersion transaction;

                    if(db.objectStoreNames.contains("client")) {
                        var storeReq = db.deleteObjectStore("client");
                    }

    const employeeData = [
            { id: "00-01", name: "gopal", age: 35, email: "gopal@tutorialspoint.com" },
            { id: "00-02", name: "prasad", age: 32, email: "prasad@tutorialspoint.com" }
         ];

            var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("client", {keyPath: "id"});

            for (var i in employeeData) {
               objectStore.add(employeeData[i]);
            }

                  }

      request.onsuccess = function(e) {
        var db =  e.target.result;

        console.log("Success");
        console.log(db);


   var transaction = db.transaction(["client"]);
            var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("client");
            var request = objectStore.get("00-02");

            request.onerror = function(event) {
               alert("Unable to retrieve daa from database!");
            };

            request.onsuccess = function(event) {
               // Do something with the request.result!
               if(request.result) {
                  alert("Name: " + request.result.name + ", Age: " + request.result.age + ", Email: " + request.result.email);
               }

               else {
                  alert("Kenny couldn't be found in your database!");
               }
            };


      };

      request.onerror = function(e) {
            console.log(e);
      };
```

In Chrome it doesn't work at all. I get an

```
DOMException: The user denied permission to access the database.
```

In Firefox it works as shown above. However, when I change the name of the database to, say, `myindexeddb`, it doesn't work anymore. I get an `UnknownError`.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In chrome, go to chrome://settings/content and ensure the top radio button is selected. Also check the Manage Exceptions list to see if that domain is explicitly blocked.

Comment: "the top radio button" is fairly imprecise, and it can change over time. Case in point, that page in the current version of Chrome doesn't have any radio buttons at all. Specifying what the radio button is that should be selected would help people find where it's now located.

Comment: @Elezar yes, totally agree. I wish I'd included screenshots. I'd delete this now-unhelpful answer if I could but seems like one cannot delete an accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I followed these steps:

1. Go to url `chrome://settings/content` in a new Chrome tab
2. Click `Cookies`
3. Uncheck `Block third-party cookies`

This should resolve the error.